# Sponsor Tag Help Need

Tags: php, html

I'm using the following code to add "rel=" tags to certain affiliate links. While this code works well with text links, it doesn't work with button links.

Does anyone know how to update this code for button links?

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("a").each(function(){
                    if($(this).attr("href").indexOf("amazon") != -1 
                       || $(this).attr("href").indexOf("amzn") != -1) {
                       
                        $(this).attr("rel","sponsored noopener");
                    }
                });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: What is a "button link"? Do you mean a `form` with a `GET` method and a submit button? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I am using This code in [Automanila.com](https://automanila.com/) you can check